# Docker Swarm: Does it let two containers in different hosts to communictae?

Tags: docker, boot2docker, docker-swarm

I set up swarm cluster with two machine. It work as desired. I'm able to launch container on desired node based on constraint filter. However when I'm trying to ping one container in one node from container in  another node, it fail. It does not recognize it. **Is it as expected or I did something wrong in setting swarm cluster?**

*Other Details*:

- machine 1(10.0.0.4) as both host/node
- machine 2(10.0.0.21) as node
- Swarm agent is 10.0.0.4:2374(ip :port)

***The output of info command it's:***

```
docker -H tcp://10.0.0.4:2374 info
Containers: 11
strategy: spread
Filters: affinity, health, constraint, port, dependency
Nodes: 2
 machine1: 10.0.0.4:2375
  └ Containers: 6
  └ Reserved CPUs: 0 / 25
  └ Reserved Memory: 0 B / 24.76 GiB    
 machine2: 10.0.0.21:2375
  └ Containers: 5
  └ Reserved CPUs: 0 / 25
  └ Reserved Memory: 0 B / 24.76 GiB
```

Comment: If you want support for multi-host networking, you should use docker-experimental with the support for vxlan. Here is the [readme](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/master/experimental/compose_swarm_networking.md) explaining how to set this up. Native swarm support for libnetwork and multi-host networking will be there when libnetwork will be merged upstream (docker 1.9).

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm seeing the same issue. Curious if you figured out what about your networking settings wasn't right.

Answer (score 2):

[Overlay networks](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/dockernetworks/#an-overlay-network) was introduced in Docker 1.9 (Nov 2015). It allows containers in different nodes (hosts) to be part of the same network and communicate.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, from the docs "Docker Swarm is native clustering for Docker. It turns a pool of Docker hosts into a single, virtual host." https://docs.docker.com/swarm/

Comment: Yes.. It says so and i am  expecting that if i use swam cluster , then container running on different host should be able to ping each other but i am unable to ping two container running on different host.

Comment: then enter in a container with a `docker exec -it container_id bash` and debug why it can't, see the other, looking at the routing table, the ip address, the mask, enter the other container and do the same

Comment: Ok . I will check it... Also if i launch two container on different node using same image id(i.e same image is there in both docker daemon running on two different node), same IP is assigned to them.

Answer (score 1):

It looks docker swarm is more like managing tool and scheduler. I have to use some other tool like weave or ambassador to connect two container in different host .  Anyhow, docker swarm is good clustering tool and help me setup thing as i desire.